# How can I sort outputs of a function from lowest to highest?

Tags: swift, xcode, sorting

```
import UIKit

import GameKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let poolBalls = [Int](1...8)
var shuffledPoolBalls = [Int]()

@IBOutlet weak var numLab1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numLab2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numLab3: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func hitBalls(_ sender: UIButton) {
    generateNumbers()
}

func generateNumbers() {
    shuffledPoolBalls = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: poolBalls) as! [Int]
    numLab1.text = String(shuffledPoolBalls[0])
    numLab2.text = String(shuffledPoolBalls[1])
    numLab3.text = String(shuffledPoolBalls[2])

}
```

}

I can't add screenshot here, sorry about that. The point is; when I run this code, I see random and non-repeated 3 numbers on screen. Thats ok but they are not sorted from lowest to highest. Think about that 1st generated number is 7 (on numLab1), 2nd generated number is 4 (on numLab2) and 3rd generated number is 1 (on numLab3). I see numbers on screen as "7-4-1" but I want to see them as "1-4-7". How can I manage that?

I solve that with Duncan's answer. Thats how I wrote my func;

```
func generateNumbers() {
    shuffledPoolBalls = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: poolBalls) as! [Int]

    let firstThree = shuffledPoolBalls.prefix(3).sorted()

    numLab1.text = String(firstThree[0])
    numLab2.text = String(firstThree[1])
    numLab3.text = String(firstThree[2])

}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. It looks like "shuffledPoolBalls" will contain an array of `Int`s from 1 to 8 in random order. Are you saying that you want to take the first 3 elements in that array, sort them in numeric order, and put those values into your labels numLab1, numLab2, and numLab3?

Comment: First of all thank you for your interest. I'm new on Swift, learning generating random numbers without repeating. I learned how to generate and see outputs on labels. When I run this code, I see non-repeated random numbers on screen, its ok I want that. The next step I want to get over was sort those numbers from lowest to highest. For example if generated numbers are 7-2-5 I want to see as 2-5-7 on screen. I searched solutions here, found different ways of sort codes, tried them into my code and I had errors. I think I don't know where to put sort codes and how.

Comment: @DuncanC I completely agree, actually. Plus the OP has "gone away" right after posting, which is wrong behavior.

Comment: I think I did it clear enough, yes maybe my words are poor, its not my main language but I tried my best to state my problem. I'm newbie, trying to do sth new for me, asking for help, searched before asking this question (I really did, more than 6 hours), I'm doing sth wrong I don't know. @DuncanC

Comment: Two experienced iOS developers couldn't make any sense of your question as asked. That's strong evidence that you did **not** state your question clearly enough. Matt and I have both stated what we thought you were asking. Use that language if you want, but go back and make your question more clear if you want an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh lordy. This is not complicated. Matt and I gave you enough information to figure out. Here is a complete solution:

```
shuffledPoolBalls = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: poolBalls) as! [Int]

let firstThree = shuffledPoolBalls.prefix(3).sorted()
```

And by the way, shuffling arrays is not hard:

```
func shuffled(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var result = array
    for i in 0 ..< array.count {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
        result.swapAt(i, index)
    }
    return(result)
}
```

And with a little more work you could make the above shuffle an array of any arbitrary type using Generics.

Comment: Thank you Duncan, I'll check that out and work for it when i go home

Comment: I have 3 UILabels aligned left to right. Each labels are connected to function 1by1 and function creates random numbers to each labels. How can I sort orders of labels from lowest to highest. Thats my question. Yes this works in playground, generates random number, i know sorted code but I can't use this code to sort order of my labels.

Comment: Yes it works..! Thank you Duncan. I was writing your code wrong way and now I fix my fault. Thank you man, I got the point, learned a new thing and I'll study on that. Have fun on code!

Answer (score 0):

As Duncan C said, doesn't make sense shuffle the full array, keep only first 3 elements and sort it, a better solution could be get N random elements from the array (and make sure that they are unique) and, after that, sort them.

This should work

```
    var shuffledPoolBalls : [Int] = []
    while shuffledPoolBalls.count < 3 {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(poolBalls.count)))
        if !shuffledPoolBalls.contains(poolBalls[randomIndex]) {
            shuffledPoolBalls.append(randomIndex)
        }
    }
    shuffledPoolBalls = shuffledPoolBalls.sorted()
    numLab1.text = String(shuffledPoolBalls[0])
    numLab2.text = String(shuffledPoolBalls[1])
    numLab3.text = String(shuffledPoolBalls[2])
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You take an array of numbers from 1...10. You shuffle them into random order. Then you sort them BACK into numeric order. Then you install the first 3 items into labels. Why shuffle them if you're going to immediately sort them again? The results would ALWAYS be 1 2 3.

Comment: @DuncanC I see your point, I tried to keep the original logic, even if it doesn't make sense. I have edited with a better logic

Comment: Yes It is always 1-2-3. Anyway, thank your for your interest. Still searching, If I find anything I'll let this post know :)